# Example for a simple string response to HttpClient request in .aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, httpclient, response

I'm just trying to respond with a string to HttpClient POST request, but my webpage always responds with the whole HTML text plus other things.

I'm a noob and i would appreciate a simple example about how to make a simple string response to a request.

I've tried Response.Clear(), Response.ClearContent(), writing strings into response, etc. but i don't know what i'm doing exactly and doesn't seems to work.

Any help or link to one example?^(i've been googlin all day but never found something simple and never about responses, always about requests) I'm using c#.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Btw i have the code in the Page_Load method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use http handler for that. Add generic handler to your project and use Response.Write

Default handler allready is returning simple string response "Hello world" by default.

[image]